Как laravel склоняет название миграций?
Смотря обучающие видео по ларавель удивился такой вещи как названия миграций, лаварель сам склоняет их в зависимости от названия модели, хотел бы узнать как он это делает?
Например, при создании модели Currency, лара сразу создает миграцию "create currencies". Он же не просто в конце добавляет s  а меняет само изначальное слово.

@Kromster добавил

Идете в исходные коды и смотрите?

На сколько я помню, в Laravel для этих целей используется библиотека Doctrine Inflector
